# load google maps apis scripts when needed? jquery.getScript()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I am using a google map with the full maps api on my website. The map is only visible and used once a specific link (e.g. Show Map) is clicked. Since this maps api is a rather large js file I want to load the api only when it's needed and not on page load like i'm doing it right now.

Right now I have this in my `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAnf9W..." type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I am using jQuery and I have a seperate script.js file where I store all my javascript.

The map I only shown when I click the following item:

```
$('#googleMap').live('click', function(e) {
```

Is it possible to use jquery getScript() to load the above scripts only when this link is clicked? Or at least load it "onLoad()" and not "onDomReady"?

Comment: Yes you can do this, could you post a brief example of your maps activation code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to include both of those scripts. You only need:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Secondly, you can use the [google loader](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/) (see the "Dynamic Loading" section) to fire up maps when the user requests it, like this:

```
$("#foo").click(function() {
    google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){
        alert('maps API loaded!');
        var map; 
        // do stuff with your map
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me this error in console "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load' ". Any suggestions to fix?? Thanks

Comment: that's because you need to load the Google API before accessing ``google.load``: ``https://www.google.com/jsapi``